# Product BOM (bill of material): cost update... do I have to use a tree structure?

Tags: c#, hierarchy

I'm working on a Product BOM (bill of material) and I'm stucked. This is my class diagram:

- A Component has ComponentItems. A ComponentItem has a Component and a quantity. Example: Component ABC has 3 Component C1 and 2 Component C2.
- A Product has ComponentItems and ProductItems (similar to ComponentItems but for Products).

Each Component has a unit cost so a ComponentItem has a total cost. And a Component composed by ComponentItems has a total cost too (sum of ComponentItems cost).

This structure lets me create any Product/Component hierarchy.
I'm validating loops in insert/update of products and components.

I want to have each cost updated in database, I don't want to calculate cost using objects every time I have to use a Product/Component. I mean, if I update the unit cost of Component ABC, his parent component cost should be updated and so on --> the update is propagated in the hierarchy.

What's the best way to implement this? I was thinking of a tree representation. When a component is updated, I retrieve all related components/products and build a tree. Then I have to update first level parents of the component and do the same with parents of this parents.

Comment: Is anyone telling you that you're required to use trees?  There are a lot of different ways you can implement this...

Comment: I dont' have to use trees. Any solution is welcomed :)

Comment: So, to be clear, you're writing a program that is going to be used solely for generating Product BOMs?

Comment: No, it's part of a bigger program. When I save an invoice (sale), I have to save unit cost of each product. This is one of the reasons why I have to have costs updated in db. I can't retrieve all children of each product to get its cost. Cost has to be pre-calculated in db. Also because I use rentability (sometimes) to calculate product price.

Comment: Is this program client or server side?

Comment: There's no separation between client and server. DBMS is MS SQL Server 2008 Express.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple tree structure would be best.

E.g. Something like

```
class Component {
    List<Component> children;
    Component parent;
    decimal _unitCost;

    public void addComponent(Component c) { children.add(c); UnitCost += c.UnitCost; } 

    public decimal UnitCost { 
       get {return unitCost;} 
       set { 
         if (parent != null) { 
            //update the parent cost, which will in turn update its parent etc.
            parent._unitCost -= UnitCost; parent.UnitCost += value; 
         }
         unitCost = value; 
       }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1) UnitCost is a property, not a method acording to your code. 2) A component has many parents, components and products. 3) A component has 5 units of another component so you can't say that parent's cost is calculated the way you did and each parent can have different quantities of that component.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought it was a one-to-many parent to child relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The [Decorator Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx) might be a good way to approach this.

There's a good chapter from Head First Design Patterns available [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/hfdesignpat/chapter/ch03.pdf) that talks about using Decorator in a similar context.